# Start process as <interactive> to use NTLM token

Tags: vb.net, windows, proxy, authorization

I want to build a small application similar to [Run As](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) (Windows native) and [DropMyRights](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2007/08/13/update-on-dropmyrights.aspx).

A simple form with a text box which will hold the path to the program that i want to run, and a dropdown to select the account to impersonate (`<system>`, `<interactive>`, or "user NameLastname") when starting the child process.

Just in case this is not enough reason to point me to the right direction, here goes the answer to "why would you want to do that?"

I noticed that some of my applications, like Google Calendar Sync, Google Drive Sync and Chrome autoupdater (not chrome.exe), when run as `<system>` can't pass through the proxy (ISA/TMG).

I do not have access to the server config settings, so i have to do this client-side.

The goal is to have the child process running as `<interactive>`, and use the NTLM token.

How can i pass `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` or `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` to the process?

I can't pass username/password/domain because we authenticate on the domain using smartcard logon.
That means i don't even know my Active Directory password.

---

Answering questions:

> It isn't clear what you mean by `<system>` and `<interactive>`. Please be
>   more specific. Do you mean you want to launch processes in your logon
>   session but have them run as SYSTEM? –  Harry Johnston

By `interactive` i mean the logged on user credentials. Could be local, but in my case i need the domain credentials.
To be even more specific, i want to use the token already generated by the proxy.

I do not want to launch processes as `system`.
I want `system` processes to connect to the internet using my (already provided and approved by ISA/TMG) credentials.

More info about this here: [What is Interactive Logon?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780095%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> Hmmm. The Chrome updater isn't a normal application, it's a system
>   service. Are you trying to run system services in the logged on user's
>   context? –  Harry Johnston

That's right. Exactly what i want to do.
**But**, Google Updater does not appear on the services list.
It's a scheduled task.
And changing the task to be executed with my credentials doesn't work. Still can not bypass the proxy.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by `<system>` and `<interactive>`.  Please be more specific.  Do you mean you want to launch processes in your logon session but have them run as SYSTEM?

Comment: OK, at the beginning you talk about wanting to create a tool that will launch child processes, and one of the options is "interactive".  That would seem redundant, because that's what you get when you launch an application in the normal way, e.g., just double-clicking the executable.  Can you explain what your proposed tool would do (in the "interactive" case) that would be different from double-clicking the specified executable?

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that NTLM proxy authentication using existing credentials is only available to an application if it uses the appropriate Microsoft APIs to access the internet.  I don't know offhand whether this is true for the applications you mention.

Comment: Hmmm.  The Chrome updater isn't a normal application, it's a system service.  Are you trying to run system services in the logged on user's context?

Comment: A scheduled task is a normal application, so you should just be able to run the relevant command line directly.  However, Google Update appears to use *both* scheduled tasks and system services, so it's hard to be sure how these are interacting and which is responsible for accessing the network.  Unfortunately, I don't believe there is any realistic way of making someone else's system service run in the logged-on users context.